# Remote hard reboot using APC Smart-UPS 1500

Tags: hardware, electrical-power, ups, remote-access

I have a situation where every now and then a server crashes (so Powerchute software won't help) and needs a "hard reboot" - someone needs to switch it off and on again manually. It would be great to be able to do it remotely.

I know there are Power Distribution Units (for example, http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=70) but I'd like if it could be achieved using specifically APC Smart-UPS 1500.

Any ideas if it's possible at all? If possible, what management card or accessory is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it with this optional network management card installed in the UPS:

http://www.apcc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=AP9630

Comment: This looks somewhat promising but I'm not 100% sure. Looks like it would allow using PowerChute Network Shutdown to "perform graceful, unattended operating system shutdown" but if the server has already crashed I basically need to switch the power outlet from UPS to server off and on again. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, Powerchute can be used to perform a graceful shutdown of the connected equipment during a power event, but the management card also allows you to shut down\reboot\sleep the UPS which will allow you to power cycle the equipment attached to the UPS.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: @SiimK We used this card at another company. It handles the shutdowns properly and the startups work well too.  Basically once AC power is restored you can have it send AC to the servers which when the BIOS are configured to will automatically start them all.  I think there was a delay capability as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, I too had this issue.  I went with a DIY solution, sort of.  I purchased the "Firecracker" and an Apliance Module  (both included in a starter pack $29) from X10 Home Automation.  You can then use the included X10 home sofware to control the appliance module and shut off the power to the PC.  Obviously, to turn it back on, the "Firecracker" and software must be on another PC in the area.

Hope this helps.